# GTKのスクロールバーについて。

Tags: c, gtk

#### main.c

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void hoge(GtkWidget *widget,gchar *text)
{

}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *vbox;
  GtkWidget *hbox;
  GtkWidget *sw;
  GtkWidget *textview;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "質問です。");
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  vbox = gtk_vbox_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

  sw = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
  gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(sw), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), sw, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

  textview = gtk_text_view_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(sw), textview);
  hoge(textview,"");

  hbox = gtk_hbox_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 5);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hbox, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

**質問内容は以下の２つです。**
  1. swを大きくし,hboxを小さくするにはどうすればよいか？
  2. スクロールバーは既存のものとして、他のデザインはないか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1つめの質問について、まずコードを提示しておきます。

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void hoge(GtkWidget *widget,gchar *text)
{

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *vbox;
    GtkWidget *hbox;
    GtkWidget *sw;
    GtkWidget *textview;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "質問です。");
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(vbox, 200, 150);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

    sw = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(sw), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), sw, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    textview = gtk_text_view_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(sw), textview);
    hoge(textview,"");

    hbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 5);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hbox, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    /*
    GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new("test");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), label, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
*/

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

gtk の box を作る関数は以下の2種類があります。

- `gtk_vbox_new()`, `gtk_hbox_new()` のように、関数名に v, h を含むもの
- `gtk_box_new()` のように、引数で横か縦かを指定するもの

今回は、質問者さんのコードでは引数で指定していたので、引数で指定する方にしました。

サイズは vbox の方に指定しています。

2つめの質問については、どういったデザインがお好みなのか解らないのと、私自身デザインに疎いので、省略させていただきます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。  gtk3.0にしたら、デザインもgtk_box_newも使えるようになりました。